# 3D Stationary Wavelet Transform implementations

Tags: wavelet

I'm interested in using a SWT to perform Multi Resolution Analysis over 3D data arrays. However I could not find any software package that implements it. The Matlab Toolbox of wavelets (the most complete I think) only has 3D DWT and 2D SWT, so my questions are:

1. There exists a working implementation of 3D SWT out there?
2. If not, how can I implement it? (some references maybe)

Comment: Have you checked the Wikipedia article on the [topic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_wavelet_transform)? It has 8 references

Comment: L2W implements a locally stationary wavelet approach, is that useful to you? Link: https://github.com/cran/LS2W

Comment: I know this is YOUR question. But do you really need 3D SWT? It could be huge, and less efficient than other less redundant methods?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There as a general [n-dimensional SWT](http://pywavelets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/swt-stationary-wavelet-transform.html#multilevel-n-dimensional-swtn) for Python in the PyWavelets package as of the 0.5.0 release.

Basic usage with `data` stored in a NumPy array would be as follows (shown here for a 4-level decomposition and Debauchies 'db2' wavelet).  PyWavelets uses the same wavelet naming conventions as the Matlab Wavelet Toolbox.

```python
import pywt
coeffs = pywt.swtn(data, wavelet='db2', level=4)
```

The example above takes <2 seconds for a 128x128x128 data array on my system.

If you are willing to [build from source](http://pywavelets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#install), there is also an n-dimensional inverse SWT available in the master branch.  Note that the inverse stationary wavelet transform is not currently implemented in a very efficient manner (particular for larger number of levels of decomposition).

In 3D, the SWT is redundant by a factor of `(1 + 7*L)` for an `L`-level decomposition (Although the implementation in PyWavelets currently returns the approximation coefficients at every level, not just the final one, leading to a redundancy of `8*L` in 3D).

Comment: Great news!! I hope PyWavelet package keep improving over time.